# How do you change the Cp/Ct array values within FLORIS?

Tags: floris

I'd like to run a FLORIS simulation to calculate the wake for a specific turbine. Currently, the input file given in FLORIS is the "example_input.json" which defines the Cp and Ct values for the NREL 5MW at different wind speeds.

I want to run a simulation for a different turbine and I have the array values for that turbine. I'm wondering if there is an easier way to change the redefine the Cp/Ct array values within FLORIS/python rather than manually typing the array values in the .json input file.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the `change_turbine` handle in the `floris` object. It is used as follows, say you want to change the power and thrust tables for turbine 0, 1 and 2 in your floris object called `fi`:

```
fi.change_turbine(
    turb_num_array=[0, 1, 2],
    turbine_change_dict={
        "power_thrust_table": new_power_thrust_table,
        }
)
```

where `new_power_thrust_table` is a dict with three keys:  `power` (the power coefficients), `thrust` (the thrust coefficients), and `wind_speed` (the wind speeds). Each should contain one array or list defining the new values (respectively, new power coefficients, thrust coefficients, and wind speeds to which the former two belong).

Also, you may want to change the turbine rotor diameter at the same time, for example to 140 m. You can do that with:

```
fi.change_turbine(
    turb_num_array=[0, 1, 2],
    turbine_change_dict={
        "power_thrust_table": new_power_thrust_table,
        "rotor_diameter": 140.
        }
)
```

Alternatively, say you want to copy over the turbine properties from the first turbine of a different floris object, `fi_b`, you could do something like:

```
fi.change_turbine(
    turb_num_array=[0, 1, 2],
    turbine_change_dict={
        "power_thrust_table": fi_b.floris.farm.turbines[0].power_thrust_table,
        "rotor_diameter": fi_b.floris.farm.turbines[0].rotor_diameter
    }
)
```